# $P\left(X+\frac{10}{X}>7\right)$ of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Problem: 
$X$ has a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,10]$. Find $P\left( X + \frac{ 10 } { X } >7\right)$.

So far, I have the PDF $f(x) = 1/10$ and CDF $F(x) = x/10$ for $0 < x < 10$.

I was wondering how to transform this information to help me solve the above probability. 
How do I solve a probability function containing a random variable?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$x+\dfrac{10}{x}-7>0~~\implies~~x^2-7x+10=\left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2-\frac{9}{4}>0$$
**Added:** You're missing part of the solution.
$$\begin{align*}P\left(X+\frac{10}{X}>7\right)&=P\left(\left(X-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2>\frac{9}{4}\right)\\[1ex]&=P(0<X<2)+P(X>5)\\[1ex]&=F(2)-F(0)+1-F(5)\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you! That really helps to transform the probability into something more recognizable. My next question is how does the uniform distribution come into play here? Do I integrate the above equation from 0 to 10?

Comment: @m10islife You can use the CDF you determined, since $F(k)=P(X<k)$.

Comment: I solved the equation to get 1 - P(X < 5), and then used the CDF to determine 1 - P(X < 5) = 1 - (5/10) = 1/2. Does that seem correct?

Comment: @m10islife I've added some more info to my answer.